# how to load data while scrolling in div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

Today I saw my Facebook account and scroll the contend bottom. After some time I found it load more -2 data while scrolling (scroll position same where it was previously). I think it is new functionality given by Facebook. Previously they first go to bottom and get that event than load the data example pull to refresh. Can we do load new data while scrolling so that it look all data in same page ?

http://jsfiddle.net/N5LZB/28/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#fullContainer').on('scroll', function () {
      if ($(this).scrollTop() === 0 ) {
         // alert('--')
         if(file_show_counter>0){
            var precontent=$("#preRealTimeContents").html();
            //$("#loadingImg").hide();
            $("#realTimeContents").html($("#preRealTimeContents").html() + '<div style="clear:both;"></div>');
            console.log("preRealTimeContents : " + $("#preRealTimeContents").height());
            //$("#preRealTimeContents").html('');
            $("#preRealTimeContents").html(pages[--file_show_counter]+ '<div style="clear:both;"></div>');
            $("#fullContainer").scrollTop(
               $("#preRealTimeContents").height()
            );
         }
      }
      else if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight ) {                                        if(++file_show_counter<count) {      
         //alert(file_show_counter);
         $("#preRealTimeContents").html($("#realTimeContents").html());
         $("#realTimeContents").html(pages[file_show_counter+1]+'<div style="clear:both;"></div>');
         $("#fullContainer").scrollTop(
            $("#preRealTimeContents").height()-  $("#fullContainer").height()              
         );
      }else {
         file_show_counter--;
      }                                                     
   }    
   });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Is requirement to begin displaying `page_1`, with `page_2` - `page_5` not displayed, then display `page_2` - `page_5` when `scoll` ? Thanks

Comment: the requirement is two display two pages at one time please check my fiddle and inspect it ..you will get idea want i want

Comment: @guest271314 please check http://jsfiddle.net/N5LZB/28/.It first display page_4 and page_5.I need visible div concept.if user know I am in preRealTimeContents div it load more data page_3 .now if user have page_3 and page_4 display .and scroll bottom user know is he in realTimeContents it load page_5 and

Answer (score 0):

Try this (pattern)

css

```
#realTimeContents div {
    padding-top : 8px;
    padding-bottom : 8px;
}
```

js (updated)

```
$(function () {

  var page_0 = "Shikhar Dhawan is an Indian international cricketer."; // `page_1`

  var page_1 = "Rohit Gurunath Sharma is an Indian international cricketer."; // `page_2`

  var page_2 = "Virat Kohli is an Indian cricketer."; // `page_3`

  var page_3 = "Suresh Raina is currently a player of Indian Cricket Team"; // `page_4`

  var page_4 = "Yuvraj Singh is an Indian international cricketer."; // `page_5`

  var pages = [page_0, page_1, page_2, page_3, page_4];

   $("#fullContainer")
   .find("#preRealTimeContents")
   .html("<div id=0>" + pages[0] + "</div>")
   .parent("#fullContainer")
   .one("scroll", function (e) {
      $.each(pages.slice(1, 5), function (k, v) {
        $("#realTimeContents")
        .append("<div id=" + (++k) + ">" + v + "</div>");
        // append `2` `pages`,
        // adjust for number
        // of `pages` to append
        // i.e.g., `0` - `4`
         return (k != 2)

      });
    });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/h95h5/

Comment: it is not a correct answer..I have to show two pages at one time

Comment: @user2484319 Please see updated post and jsfiddle. The number of `pages` appended should be adjustable. Thanks

Comment: I think you can't understand my question.I will explain again.

Comment: First time user run his fiddle it display page_4, and page_5 in preRealTimeContents, preRealTimeContents contend div.

Comment: Now if user scroll to bottom it mean when user scroll in any div in downward direction it do nothing because we have only five pages .we already display last page (page_5). But when user scroll up direction it will load page page_3 and unload page_5 from the dom.

Comment: In my fiddle I do all thing correct .But I am doing all thing on getting top and bottom event of div .So user need to  hit top and bottom while new loading and previous  data.

Comment: @user2484319 Perhaps clearer concept of requirement now. A piece composed recently, perhaps merged with above may help ? See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23005776/infinite-scroll-without-external-content and jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/bG5N8/ . similar requirement ?

Comment: @guest271314 thanks for help ..but I think it not help can you change my fiddle using that concept..

Comment: @guest271314 I don't have static data I may be have 100 pages or 500 .I need some geneic function of visible concept .i saw Facebook implement this

Comment: @NaveenSharma Not certain which requirement is which requirement now ? Please illuminate . Both pieces may be adjustable to accomodate `n` pages. Requirement from original post , and comments appear to indicate `2` pages ? could possibly include `$.ajax()`, other functions within either pattern ?

Comment: @guest271314 i will can we load data while scrolling ..?i saw this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026751/capture-first-visible-div-id-while-scrolling-viewport

Comment: can we load data using more data using view port example .

Comment: @user2484319 Potentially difficult if requirement added to at comment, not included at original post ? Mainly attempted to post a _pattern_ that could be adjusted, modified to scale to various potential requirements. Happy to help if able. Would requirement be to expand single element to fill entire viewport ?

Comment: I just want want user should have smith scrolling .without knowing any data is appending or pre appending .I need to add data while scrolling

Comment: Would requirement be to expand single element to fill entire viewport ?  yes sir ..sorry sir I write anything wrong

Comment: When I will get I am in prerealtimecontend div. I need to add div in upper and removing realtime contend div (or you can swipe condent) .

Comment: Either jsfiddle at post http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/h95h5/, or in comment  above http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/bG5N8/ should be able to accomplish that requirement, if include pieces to get data. btw, not not familar with `fb` that site's features. just composed patterns that could possibly be utilized to be adjustable for further development. Perhaps post another question including requirement that data be retrieved and included /incorporated within rendering pieces ?

Comment: Sir I request first see my fiddle and given in Question .and check I load data when I got event of top and bottom and data change of div

Comment: @user2484319 Did. Went to jsfiddle from original post. Perhaps not able to interpret requirement accurately (here). Just try to share a possible pattern / template as interpreted requirement. Thanks

Comment: please look this Question I posted new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23050431/can-we-load-data-while-scrolling-in-jquerry