# Returning to the previous scroll position after div reload in php

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

When I reload the div content that time scrollbar is coming on top, I want when div reload that time scrollbar position same where I left.

```
<style type="text/css">
div.scrollbar {
height: 655px;
overflow: auto;

}
</style>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(function() {
  function newPost() {
      $("#newpost").empty().load("slide/parts/extruderRight1.php");
   }
    var res = setInterval(newPost, 30000);
 });
</script>

// How to Add scroll bar maintain where I left load("slide/parts/extruderRight1.php")

<div class="voice {}"class="voice {}"><span class="label"><b>To Do List</b></a></span></div>

<div id="scrollbar" class="scrollbar">
<div id="newpost">

            </div>
        </div>
```

What I have to do so I can run proper or add anything into the my code  i wanted to resume it to the previous scrolled position suggest me or any changes required I am stuck on this step

Comment: Have you tried assigning id's to your containers ex: div id = "1" etc and allocating them with js ?

Comment: can you explain in proper @pc

Comment: So with using div id's your js can assign currently viewed div. The trick is to either set a cookie or better to pass a variable into your url of that page with currently viewed div id so your browser can distinct this as new url. Please take a look at this page. It will give you a lot of insight into your problem. : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026751/capture-first-visible-div-id-while-scrolling-viewport